# Gratis android app to find large files on device

Tags: gratis, android, file-management

For some reason, I am using 20/25GB on my tablets internal storage, and I can't for the life of me find what is taking up so much space, as I don't have a lot of apps and my downloads folder is clear.

I am looking for a gratis (free) android application that will allow me to locate and delete large files on internal, and external storage.

Requirements:

- Must be free
- Should be ad-free, but not required
- Must be able to locate large files on both internal and external storage
- Must return a list of large files, and I must be able to choose which ones I want to delete. This search result must differentiate which files are on either the internal or external storage
- I should be able to set a limit to search for a certain file size
- Would be neat if it could remove app cache's as well (instead of manually removing them from each app in the settings)

Comment: There are also some questions on our sister-site Android.SE you may wish to consult: [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575) / [Android “Internal Storage” used but not reported](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28110/16575). See also [this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=34) for more candidates ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en), it's basically a Windirstats for Android:

- free
- located large file:

[image: Located large file]

<sub>Click for larger image</sub>

- select internal or external storage

[image: Select internal or external storage]

<sub>Click for larger image</sub>